# Database compatability between releases of mediawiki

Tags: mysql, upgrade, mediawiki

I am running an old [release 1.22.6] version of mediawiki which I am finally being forced to upgrade or replace. I am considering creating a new subdomain using the 1.32.0 release of mediawiki. And then I intend to restore a backup of my old version databases and image files to the new version.

My main concern is about database changes between the versions. Will the backups be compatible with the new wiki version?

I also have the same concern about my modified LocalSettings.php file.

My mysql server version is 5.7.25

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this not a programming question. It should rather be addressed to the vendor's support.

Comment: Do you know a URL for mediawiki support. I cannot find one.

Comment: Where or how did you search? https://www.mediawiki.org/: On the left there's a whole section called "Support"?

Comment: <face palm> Duh, I must be getting senile in my old age. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database can be migrated to the new version, as described in the [upgrading manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading). The one somewhat-exception is the pageview data, check out the documentation for the [HitCounters extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HitCounters) if you want to keep that.

`LocalSettings.php` might need to be updated, check the release logs or the documentation for the configuration variables you are modifying. It really depends on what you have in it.